# Save the thumbnails of dropzonejs in php

Tags: dropzone.js

Hi  I was new in the web development work and upon googling i find dropzonejs that uploads multiple photos perfectly. I was just wondering on how to save the thumbnails of the same photos into another folder or path and save it to database also.

Please help, I'm newbie , I just understand the code but can't create one by my self

Thanks in advance,

Gene